# Question about difference between "rent" & "hire" & "take"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I want to rent a car.
>
> I want to hire a car.
>
> I want to take a car. ( Taxi )

What is the difference between these sentences in meaning? I need to say here I am not sure to have chosen the right word in the last sentence.

Thank you do much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*Rent* means to pay money to borrow something.  So when you rent a car, you'll be driving it yourself.

*Hire* means to pay money to have someone do something.  You aren't really hiring a car, you're hiring the driver of the car, who will then take you were you need.

*Take* is used with a means of transportation to express that you want to use that means of transportation.  *I want to take car* simply means you want to use a car to get somewhere, presumably instead of another means of transportation such as a bike, or walking.

Comment: That definition of hire is incorrect. Hiring does not imply being driven.

Comment: I haven't heard "to hire a car" before, to be honest.  This could be a regional difference I've never heard.  :)

Comment: The phrase 'car hire' or 'hiring a car' is very common in the UK.

Comment: Guess my AmE-ness is showing here.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Hire and rent are basically synonyms and are interchangeable. There's a few situations where one or the other wouldn't be suitable e.g. Renting an apartment or house; you wouldn't hire a house. However, you might hire someone to paint your house, but you wouldn't rent someone.

Comment: Not really, you hire people, but you rent places or tools.

Comment: You can hire tools too. You hire people and you rent flats and houses, but apart from that they're pretty much interchangeable.